# Screen brightness very dim on a Dell XPS 13 (2013)

Tags: dell, brightness, 13.04

I just installed Xubuntu 13.04 on a new Dell XPS 13 Ultrabook. When I boot up the screen brightness is EXTREMELY dim. Adjusting the screen brightness doesn't do anything. This is obviously a very new bug with 13.04.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

here are a couple kernel boot parameters you can try

- `acpi_osi=Linux`
- `acpi_backlight=vendor`
- `acpi_osi='!Windows 2012'`

This is there you add that code, I had to use the 3ed one to get mine working right, it may be necessary to use 1 or 3 combined with the second one
The file to edit is :
`/etc/default/grub`
once you edit it run `sudo update-grub` then reboot


  [image]

Comment: never ever seen acpi_osi='!Windows 2012' ...

Comment: i got it from a kernel dev [here](https://bugzilla.kernel.org/show_bug.cgi?id=55161#c15)

Comment: i did google ...ty for updating the information...

Answer (score 0):

Along with @GM-Script-Writer-62850's answer, if you're using an EFI BIOS boot, you ned to go into the BIOS setup and set "Load Legacy Rom" to Enabled.

I have experimented with the minimal GRUB line to get this working and I only need `acpi_osi=Linux`

AFAIK Legacy is [anything not Windows 8](http://www.tomshardware.com/answers/id-1650859/uefi-legacy-rom-mode.html), and I've not experienced any performance hit.